# Position the radio button and label (div) of dcc.RadioItems to be next to each other inside a flexbox

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash

In the layout of my Dash app, I have flexible container containing a dcc.RadioItems component. I want all of the labels and their corresponding radio buttons to be next to each other, however I want each button-label pair to be vertically stacked. This works fine until I want to change the label to not just be text, but another Dash component (an html.Div exactly, so I can format its margins properties).

Here's the part of the layout responsible for the dcc.RadioItems and its parent container:

```
dbc.Container([

            dcc.RadioItems([

                {'label': html.Div(['Label 1'],
                 style={'margin-bottom': '20px'}), 'value': 'l1'},

                {'label': html.Div(['Label 2'],
                 style={'margin-bottom': '20px'}), 'value': 'l2'},

                {'label': html.Div(['Label 3'],
                 style={'margin-bottom': '20px'}), 'value': 'l3'}],

                id="radio-items", inline=False, labelStyle={'display': 'block'})



    ], id="container-radio", style={"display": "flex", "flex-direction": "column",
                                    "justify-content": "center", "align-items": "center"}),
```

This version makes the button-label pair appear under each other like this

```
o
label1

o
label2

o
label3
```

whereas I want it to be positioned like

```
o label1

o label2

o label3
```

I also want the RadioItems position to be centered in the parent container, both horizontally and vertically, thus the parent container style has justify-content and align-items attributes, but I assume that has little to do with my problem (might be wrong, as I am not a web-dev developer). I have tested all possible combinations of flex-direction, labelStyle and inline but were not able to get the positioning I desire. I have a feeling this problem has to do something with the underlying css classes and I am just not experienced in front-end enough to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the cause of this is the `html.Div()` inside `label`. Try adding `'display':'inline-block'` to style for all label `div`s and the problem should be solved.

```
{'label': html.Div(['Label 1'], style={'margin-bottom': '20px','display':'inline-block'}), 'value': 'l1'}
```